# Getting the following error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'" when trying to scrape with below code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Got "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'" when trying to scrape through following python code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("https://deathtimeline.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
deaths_list = soup.find(id="main-list")
deaths = deaths_list.find_all(class_="episode-deaths")
episode1 = deaths[0]
print(episode1.prettify())
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: `print(soup, deaths_list)` to see your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not getting main-list is because the site("https://deathtimeline.com/")
 is JavaScript loaded. if you check the content of page.content or view source of the site you can only see JS code.

> BeautifulSoup does not execute Javascript, so any data delivered or
>   rendered via JS will not be available to you if you scrape with
>   BeautifulSoup.

You can try using **[selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)** to get JS loaded pages